# How to make a dictionary that contains an Arabic diacritic as a key in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, diacritics, arabic-support

I am trying to make a program that converts the Arabic diacritics and letters into the Latin script. The letters work well in the program, but the diacritics can not be converted as I get an error every time I run the program.

At the beginning, I put the diacritics alone as keys but that did not work with me. please, see the last key, it contains َ  ,which is a diacritic, but do not work properly as the letters:

```
def convert(lit):
    ArEn = {'ا':'A', 'ل':'L', "و": "W", "َ":"a"}
    end_word=[]
    for i in range(len(lit)):
        end_word.append(ArEn[lit[i]])
        jon = ""

    print(jon.join(end_word))

convert("الوَ")
```

However, I tried to fix the problem by using letters attached with diacritics as keys, but the program resulted in the same error:

the dictionary:

```
ArEn = {'ا':'A', 'ل':'L', "وَ":"Wa"}
```

the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdulaziz\Desktop\converter AR to EN SC.py", line 10, in <module>
    convert("الوَ")
  File "C:\Users\Abdulaziz\Desktop\converter AR to EN SC.py", line 5, in convert
    end_word.append(ArEn[lit[i]])
KeyError: 'و'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update*: I just noticed, after years, that the letters and diacritics are put together in the first try. When I separated them, the program worked.

I just solved the problem!
I am not really sure if it is a mistake in python or something else, but as far as I know python does not support Arabic very well. Or maybe I made a problem in the program above.

I kept writing the same program and suddenly it worked very well.
I even added different diacritics and they worked properly.

```
    def convert(lit):
    ArEn = {'ا':'A', 'ل':'L', "و":"W", "َ":"a", "ُ":"w", "":""}
    end_word=[]
    for i in range(len(lit)):
        end_word.append(ArEn[lit[i]])
        jon = ""

    print(jon.join(end_word))

convert("اُلوَ")
```

the reult is

```
AwLWa
```

Answer (score 1):

The chances are rather there is a bug in the programing-code editor you are using for coding Python  than on Pyhton itself. 
Since you are using Python-3.x, the diacritics from the running progam point of view are just a single character, like any other, and there should be no issues at all.

From the cod-editor point of view, there are issues such as whether to advance one character when displaying certain special unicode characters or not, and maybe the `"` character itself can be show out of space -  when one tries to manually correct the position of the `"`, one could place it out of order, leaving the special character actually outside the quoted string -

The fact you could solve the issue by re-editing the file suggests that is indeed what happened.

One way to avoid this is to put certain special characters - specially ones that have different displaying rules, is to escape then with the `"\uxxxx"` unicode codepoint unicode sequence. This will avoid yourself or other persons having issues when editing your file again in the future, since even i yu get it working now, the editor may show then incorrectly when they are opened, and by trying to fix it one might break the syntax again.

You can use a table on the web or Python3's interactive prompt to get the unicode codepoint of each character, ensuring the code part of the program is displayed in a deterministic way in any editor - (if you add the diacritical char as a  comment on the same line, it will actually enhance the readability of your code - enormously if it is ever supposed to be edited by non Arabic speakers)

So, your above declaration, I used this snippet to extract the codepoints:

```
>>> ArEn = {'ا':'A', 'ل':'L', "و": "W", "َ":"a"}
>>> [print (hex(ord(yy)), yy ) for yy in ArEn.keys()]

0x648 و
0x644 ل
0x64e َ
0x627 ا
```

Which allows me to declare the dictionary like this:

```
ArEn = {
 "\u0648": "W",    # و
 "\u0644": "L",    # L
 "\u064e": "a",    #  ۮ
 "\u0627": "A",   # ا
}
```

(And yes, I had trouble with displaying the characters on my terminal like I said you probably had on your editor while getting these - the fatha ("\u064e"  - "a")  character is tricky ! :-)  )

Alternatively for using the codepoints in your code, is to use Python's `unicode` data module to discover and them use the actual character names - this can enhance readability further, and maybe by exploring `unicodedata` you can find out you don't even have to create this dictionary manually, but use that module instead -

```
In [16]: [print("\\u{:04x} - '{}' - {}".format(ord(yy), unicodedata.name(yy),  yy) ) for yy in ArEn.keys()]
\u0648 - 'ARABIC LETTER WAW' - و
\u0644 - 'ARABIC LETTER LAM' - ل
\u064e - 'ARABIC FATHA' - َ
\u0627 - 'ARABIC LETTER ALEF' - ا
```

And from these full text names, you can get back to the character with the `unicodedata.lookup` function:

```
>>> unicodedata.lookup("ARABIC LETTER LAM")
 'ل'
```

*notes*: 
1) This requires Python3 - for Python2 one might try to prefix each string with `u""` -  but one dealign with these characters is far better off using Python 3, since unicode support is one of the big deals with it. 
2) This also requires a terminal with a nice support for unicode characters using "utf-8" encoding - I am on a Linux system with the "konsole"  terminal. On Windows, the `idle` Python prompt might work, but not the `cmd` Python prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You might need proper indentation in python:

```
def convert(lit):
    ArEn = {'ا':'A', 'ل':'L', "و":"W", "َ":"a", "ُ":"w", "":""}
    end_word=[]
    for i in range(len(lit)):
        end_word.append(ArEn[lit[i]])
        jon = ""

    print(jon.join(end_word))

convert("اُلوَ")
```

Comment: The problem here is not indentation. As long as you have `{` for typing in a dict, Pyhton does not care how you indent it untill you match it with a `} `.

Comment: the first line `def convert(lit):`

Comment: This is a formatting error when posting the code here - otherwise  the O.P.would have reported a different error.(I edited the listed code in the question to fix it now)